# How can I properly overload the > operator as a template function in C++? Learning template overloading

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading

I want to do a regular operator overload, but with templates. So imagine:

```
template <typename Type>
bool operator> (Type &tX, Type &tY)
{
     return (tX.data > tY.data) ? tX : tY;
}
```

But I want it to work with any class or primitive. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You can't overload an operator for two primitives.

Comment: It seems weird, you're returning one of the object as `bool`...

Comment: Have you heard of [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I properly overload the > operator as a template function in C++?

1. You cannot overload the `>` operator for primitive types. The language does not allows that.
2. You cannot overload the `>` operator for user defined types in any sensible manner either. The generic implementation has no way of knowing how one instance of a user defined type can be compared with another instance of the same type.